# css: десктопный и мобильный сайты

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile-development, mobile-web

Сделал сайт, который комфортно выглядит на мониторе, но на телефоне есть некоторые дискомфортные элементы:

1) меню слишком мелкое

2) некоторые элементы сайта (например боковое меню) можно скрыть и выдавать при нажатии, чтобы больше места под основную информацию освободилось

и т.д.

В общем почти всё лечится изменением css стилей для некоторых элементов

В связи с этим вопрос - как оптимальнее и правильнее решать проблему сайтов для мобильных платформ?

Первое что приходит в голову - при загрузке сайта определять, что он запущен на мобильной платформе и запускать дублированную страничку с другими стилями (+ немного JS кода). Такой подход, как я понимаю, используется часто (например, lenta.ru и m.lenta.ru)

Второе - уже после загрузки сайта определять мобильную платформу и догружать дополнительный стиль css

Подскажите, как корректнее в 21 веке :) решать подобную задачу.

Comment: Я надеюсь вы используете viewport?

Comment: @Alexandr Maliovaniy, мы здесь все на это надеемся...

Comment: @Alexandr Maliovaniy, мне стыдно признаться, но честно говоря нет (да даже как-то и не задумывался), сайт только под десктопную версию был и возникла надобность его под мобильную платформу адаптировать. После Вашего комментария начал изучать вопрос. На что стоит обратить внимание?

Comment: Так - прочитал про viewport, не совсем понятно как оно тут применимо

Comment: @Zhihar https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp здесь всё понятно написано + примеры

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так меню сворачивают в иконку и это видно при экране равном или меньше 560px

**Что я сделал?**

При первом `медиа запросе` я уменьшил шрифты

А вот во втором уже я слепил некую иконку `span.trigger`  внутри которого `i` всё блочное и имеет высоту и ширину и видно это только при меньше 560px и эта же кнопочка вызывает меню ..саму кнопку я вынул из потока `position:fixed;` а меню само я задвинул влево `-100%` а при клике на эту кнопочку добавляю класс на jQuery `open` собственно вся магия

[здесь](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/OZdLqm?editors=0110) можешь потренироваться и подвигать окошко сниппета для проверки адаптивности

разумеется что наличие `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` обязательно

*так же можно развернуть пример на весь экран а сам браузер свернуть до нужного размера и тогда можно обойтись без codepen*

```js
$(".trigger").on("click", function() {
  $("ul").toggleClass("open");
})
```

```css
:root {
  --num: 30px;
  /*высота меню*/
}

* {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(lightgreen, green);
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 50%;
  height: var(--num);
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% - var(--num));
  right: 0;
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li a {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #fff;
}

ul li:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% - 3px);
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transition: all .7s linear;
}

ul li:hover:before {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.header__item {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2.4em;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #fff;
}

.header__item p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

@media (max-width:764px) {
  .header__item {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
  ul {
    width: 60%;
  }
  ul li a {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}

@media (max-width:560px) {
  .header__item {
    font-size: 1.6em;
  }
  ul {
    display: block;
    height: 100vh;
    width: auto;
    background: inherit;
    padding: 20px;
    left: -100%;
    right: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: auto;
    transition: 1s;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px #000;
  }
  ul li {
    padding: 10px 0;
  }
  span.trigger {
    display: block;
    background: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
  }
  span.trigger i {
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 6px;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 4px auto;
  }
  .open {
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <div class="header__item">
    Блог Пупкина Заумкина
    <p>я программист и знаю jquery</p>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <span class="trigger">
      <i></i>
      <i></i>
      <i></i>
    </span>
    <li><a href="">text1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">text2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">text3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">text4</a></li>
    <li><a href="">text5</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: Не перестаёшь удивлять, ну и название))

Comment: @Arthur  ну а чё ? нормально - исправь сам - а то мне нравится

Comment: Не-не, меня всё устраивает:)

Comment: @Arthur  исправил

Answer (score 0):

Зачем дублировать, если нужно скрыть меню или какой-то sidebar то заранее сделайте например ту же кнопку бургер-меню, прикрепите к ней toggle на открытие и закрытие боковой панели или меню, и отображайте её на мобильных устройствах, а сам сайдбар скрывайте. Обязательно пропишите viewport для корректной адаптации и меняйте css на разных медиа брейкпоинтах.

Comment: я чуть о другом = например у меню сейчас `height: 50px;`, а для мобильного телефона `height: 10%` должен быть, чтобы не мелко выглядел - вот о чём я

Comment: @Zhihar  для мобильного меню 100% высоты и скрыто , сами пункты меню прячутся под кнопку сворачиваясь в гамбургер